# Problem with tagging users in comments

Tags: bug, comments, comment-replies

I have a problem with tagging users in comments, sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

To explain better my problem which is probably a bug I've attached an image below.

You all know when it works it should look like this

[image]

but often there's no suggestion and I can't tag user in comment even if I type `@username` it doesn't show in comment.

Comment: Probably because the user is the OP and gets notified anyway. Then this will be stripped from the comment cause of redundancy.

Comment: @juergend Thanks for the reply, it makes sense :) P.S. I've tried just now to tag user in random question, it's not OP but doesn't give suggestion.

Comment: [The rules are simple, really](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) (-:

Comment: Autocompletion explicitly does not list names that will be notified already *anyway*.

Comment: @Mat thanks for the link, this is reasonable answer `2. You must include @name, where name is a reasonable match to a user's current display name. Users who have not set a display name in their profile are not notified.`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a bug but how the @-reply feature works.